# One-to-many - many-to-many challenge in ERD

Tags: database, visio, erd

I have the following problem: 
I need to create an erd for the following business rules:

- one chef can write many books
- one chefs can only work in one restaurant
- every restaurant may have many chefs working for them working there
- And a bunch of other unrelated stuff

---

How would this look in visio, in an ERD? I came up with this:
http://postimg.org/image/6t1hf1e5x/

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a ChefsInRestaurant table.Add a foreign key attribute to chief table(FK_rest_Name).
In your example ıt shows one chief can work for more than one rest.

Comment: Thank you! My incompetent database teacher was unable to do this, and recommended me, to not to go in this depth with my database, as it not needed for the assignment!